# How to check object of arrays is finished in a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm working on a google maps project where I am plotting a journey, I am using AJAX request to return the data as an array of objects, I then loop through that array and create a new array of latlng objects like shown below, this all work perfectly

```
var pathCoords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
                route = {
                    lat : data[i].latitude,
                    lng : data[i].longitude
                }

                pathCoords.push(route);
            }
```

I next plot the start and end marker and this is fine, next i loop through the `pathCoords []` and plot a moving marker along a polyline. see method below

```
    for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(coords) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                routeLine.getPath().push(latlng);
                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
                if(i === (Object.keys(data).length-1)){
                    console.log("This is the end..."+i+"co=ordinates size "+pathCoords.length);
centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);
                }

                    //console.log("data link...."+Object.keys(data).length)

            }, 200 * i, pathCoords[i]);
```

The moveMarker does what it says it does, moves the marker along, **what I'm trying to achieve is to call the method, `centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);` when the for loops ends**, this method fits and centers the map accordingly, I have searched and tried everything, and cannot figure this out, I also tried SO solutions from othere answers and this just didn't work, like method below.

```
if(i === (Object.keys(data).length-1)){
            console.log("This is the end..."+i+"co=ordinates size "+pathCoords.length);
        }
```

any help or solutions, Im essentially trying to fit the route and markers on the map, saying that I have tried using `bounds.extend(coords); map.fitbounds(bounds)` , this this not help me either, Thank you

Comment: Why the downvote, please don't downvote without saying why its quiet Cowardly, this question is not about programming is off topic, what a joke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have created closure for following function

```
 for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(coords) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                routeLine.getPath().push(latlng);
                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
                if(i === (Object.keys(data).length-1)){
                    console.log("This is the end..."+i+"co=ordinates size "+pathCoords.length);
centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);
                }

                    //console.log("data link...."+Object.keys(data).length)

            }, 200 * i, pathCoords[i]);
}
```

Here setTimeout is asynchronous, so first time it encounters in for loop,
it put function in pool to execute after timeout and continue execution of code so for loop continues and next and same until reached length,

now after timeout when function executes it has access to outer scope variable i which is now already equals length. at time of first time condition check

```
i === (Object.keys(data).length-1) // i is already equals to length-1,
```

solution will be to use [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
             (function(i){
setTimeout(function(coords) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                    routeLine.getPath().push(latlng);
                    moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
                    if(i === (Object.keys(data).length-1)){
                        console.log("This is the end..."+i+"co=ordinates size "+pathCoords.length);
    centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);
                    }

                        //console.log("data link...."+Object.keys(data).length)

                }, 200 * i, pathCoords[i]);
}(i))   
    }
```

[link to concept of closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am new too javascript and have a lot to learn, I will read the article provided and let you know how I get on thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: Thanks for this, this has solved my issue but caused me another issue which is another question for SO overflow, before I accept could you just explain, in  a short summary what youve done

Comment: I have solved my issue by using your solution thank you I am happy to accept the answer, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

I would leverage promises with `Promise.all` to deal with this problem, it would look something like this:

```
function delayedMarkerPlace(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // place the marker
            resolve();
        }, 200 * i)
    });
}

const placeMarkersPromises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    placeMarkersPromises.push(delayedMarkerPlace(i));
}

Promise.all(placeMarkersPromises).then(() => {
    // action after all markers have been placed
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have looked into promises just couldn't get my head around them, like this site I suppose get down voted for asking questions, and no reason as to why down voted lol, I will try and implement this as see if this helps thank you

Comment: yup, you shouldn't get down-vote to ask this kind of questions, we all been here! Best wishes! Johan.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a function in a loop, which means that the value of i is captured by reference which means the value of i when your timeout function executes will not be the same as when the function was created.

Try creating the function outside of the loop and passing in all the information it needs, something like: (no i didn't test this but I hope it gets the idea across.)

```
var on_call = function(coords, j, end_index) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                routeLine.getPath().push(latlng);
                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
                if(j === end_index){
                    console.log("This is the end..."+i+"coordinates size "+end_index + 1);
                    centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);
                }
            }
    for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(on_call , 200 * i, pathCoords[i], j, pathCoords.length -1);
```

Creating a function in a loop is something you want to try to avoid a lot of the time because closures can cause errors that seem strange at first.

Suggested reading: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Comment: Thank you for your answer I did not know this, "You're creating a function in a loop, which means that the value of i is captured by reference which means the value of i when your timeout function executes will not be the same as when the function was created." I will look into your solution and read your suggested link thank you again..

Comment: What is the values of j and end_index, sorry not sure what misssing here

Comment: j would be the value of the index for that step, so 0 for the first step 1 for the next step and so forth. end_index just replaces your end condition, pathCoords.length -1 would probably be the value you want to pass for it, though it looks like it may be unnecessary to pass that as a parameter, you can probably use pathCoords directly.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions create their own execution contexts. Thus, every time you call a function, a new execution context is created. If you create a setTimeout function, that function behaves asynchronously and that means that the JavaScript engine will continue to parse and execute your code line by line without waiting for your timer function to return. That means that you have lost whatever value you wanted to assign to variable i simply because you are not capturing its value in that particular execution context or scope. So in order to capture that value you have to create a closure. With a closure you enclose your code within a function creating a local scope that has its own execution context and thus allows you to grab the value of i.

```
for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
  //  this is how you do not lose the value of i
  //  waiting for setTimeout to return
  (function(i){ 
    // note the above function has a closure over setTimeout
    // this is where the magic happens because here you create the 
    // execution context or local scope you want to "link" the iteration 
    // to the timer function
    setTimeout(function(coords) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
      routeLine.getPath().push(latlng);
      moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
      if(i === (Object.keys(data).length-1)){
        console.log("This is the end..."+i+"co=ordinates size" +pathCoords.length);
   centerMapandZoom(markerStart,markerEnd,pathCoords);
      }
    }, 200 * i, pathCoords[i]);

  // the IIFE function gets executed and you pass an 
  // argument that will equal i when passed as a parameter
  // inside the IIFE function

  }(i))   
}
```

In modern browsers, you could also create local scope by using the LET declaration as a variable inside the for loop like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < whatever.length; i++){
  whatever you want;
}
```

That means you will have a more elegant solution for your problem with the downside that it may not be supported by older browsers. In other words it requires testing. There are other solutions you could implement for closures but those are more "verbose" to write and explain but if you need additional explanation or examples, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to the accepted answer, thank you for the added comments helped me understand in more detail